# i18n : translate a sentence that one of words is bold

Tags: vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I want to **translate** this **sentence** in i18n

```
Select <b>branch(s)</b> you want to send selected product
after selecting Branch Click on submit
```

As you can see , one word in above sentence is in `<b>` tag.

I have this **solution** , But I am **not** sure is this is the best way to do or not.

```
$t('part1') <b>$t('part2')</b>  $t('part3')
```

so ,do you know **better** way to **translate** this ??

Comment: You can check this link: https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/formatting.html#html-formatting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your requirement, we have to translate a message/sentence which contains HTML tag.

The solution `$t('part1') <b>$t('part2')</b>  $t('part3')` you mentioned in OP is difficult to manage and complicated. You can avoid it using the `i18n` [functional component](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/interpolation.html#slots-syntax-usage). For example **:**

Your language JSON will look like this :

```js
const messages = {
  en: {
    info: 'Select {branchText} you want to send selected product after selecting Branch Click on submit.',
    subText: 'branch(s)',
  }
}
```

Template will look like this :

```html
<i18n path="info" tag="p">
  <template v-slot:branchText>
    <b>{{ $t('subText') }}</b>
  </template>
</i18n>
```

Hope this answer will help! Thanks.

Comment: ...although I agree that in this case where you are in complete control of HTML, using `v-html` would be just fine too

Comment: @MichalLevý I'd say, who knows: better safe than sorry. If it adds a layer of security (if your locale files are stored in a less safer place or exposed to your product team idk), it's fine to have it like this. Of course, you can also add a sanitizer on top of the `v-html` too.